# Как составить программу?

Tags: vb6, pascal, php, delphi-7, c++

С клавиатуры вводится последовательность чисел, сравнить ее с числами в (массиве или текстовом документе или в базе банных или в dat файле) и если есть совпадение последовательности, вывести сообщение о совпадении чисел и вывести следующее число на форме программы. Подскажите как написать и на каком языке. Заранее спасибо.

> 1681863 18 6138 ... 386 183 861 8316 831 86 8136 813 681 863 186811

- разделены пробелом.

Comment: В качестве языка могу посоветовать суахили.

Comment: на бейсике можно все! (с)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете записать данные с консоли в **String** на языке **Java** и поиграться с методом [**substring()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

Этот метод получает строку и возращает true если данная строка содержится в вашем объекте класса **String**